# IBM-Watson assistant - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, ibm-watson

I'm trying to integrate IMB-Watson assistant on my React app, following these steps described here: [IBM cloud API docs/Watson-assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node.)
On the server-side, first I have to GET session-Id, but I'm always getting Errors:

- console return: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
- http://localhost:9000/api/watson/session - GET, return: "There was an error processing your request."
  And of course, can't continue to next steps to post message on my app.
  Where I'm wrong...?

My folders structure:

- ./client
- ./node_modules
- ./routes/api/watson.js
- .env
- server.js

Here are my files:
**server.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();

app.use(express.json());

const watsonRoutes = require("./routes/api/watson");
app.use("/api/watson", watsonRoutes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port ", port);
});
```

**watson.js**

```js
// 1. Import dependencies
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const AssistantV2 = require("ibm-watson/assistant/v2");
const { IamAuthenticator } = require("ibm-watson/auth");

// 2. Create Instance of Assistant

// 2.1 First authenticate
const authenticator = new IamAuthenticator({
  apikey: process.env.WATSON_ASSISTANT_APIKEY,
});

// 2.2 Connect to assistant
const assistant = new AssistantV2({
  version: "2020-04-01",
  authenticator: authenticator,
  url: process.env.WATSON_ASSISTANT_URL,
});

// 3. Route to Handle Session Tokens
// GET /api/watson/session
router.get("/session", async (req, res) => {
  // If successs
  try {
    const session = await assistant.createSession({
      assistantId: process.env.WATSON_ASSISTANT_ID,
    });
    res.json(session["result"]);

    // If fail
  } catch (err) {
    res.send("There was an error processing your request.");
    console.log(err);
  }
});

// 4. Handle Messages
// POST /api/watson/message
router.post("/message", async (req, res) => {
  // Construct payload
  payload = {
    assistantId: process.env.WATSON_ASSISTANT_ID,
    sessionId: req.headers.session_id,
    input: {
      message_type: "text",
      text: req.body.input,
    },
  };

  // If successs
  try {
    const message = await assistant.message(payload);
    res.json(message["result"]);

    // If fail
  } catch (err) {
    res.send("There was an error processing your request.");
    console.log(err);
  }
});

// 5. Export routes
module.exports = router;
```

[image]

```js
> reactchatbot@1.0.0 dev /Users/seldaali/Downloads/ReactChatBot
> concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"

[0] 
[0] > reactchatbot@1.0.0 server /Users/seldaali/Downloads/ReactChatBot
[0] > nodemon server
[0] 
[1] 
[1] > reactchatbot@1.0.0 client /Users/seldaali/Downloads/ReactChatBot
[1] > npm start --prefix client
[1] 
[0] [nodemon] 2.0.7
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[1] 
[1] > client@0.1.0 start /Users/seldaali/Downloads/ReactChatBot/client
[1] > react-scripts start
[1] 
[0] Server listening on port  9000
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.5/
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/seldaali/Downloads/ReactChatBot/client/public
[1] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
[1] Starting the development server...
[1] 
[1] Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run the following command: `yarn upgrade`
[1] Compiled with warnings.
[1] 
[1] src/reducers/watson.js
[1]   Line 17:3:  Assign arrow function to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export
[1] 
[1] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
[1] To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
[1] 
[0] Forbidden: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
[0]     at RequestWrapper.formatError (/Users/seldaali/Downloads/ReactChatBot/node_modules/ibm-cloud-sdk-core/lib/request-wrapper.js:275:21)
[0]     at /Users/seldaali/Downloads/ReactChatBot/node_modules/ibm-cloud-sdk-core/lib/request-wrapper.js:260:45
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
[0]     at async /Users/seldaali/Downloads/ReactChatBot/routes/api/watson.js:53:21 {
[0]   statusText: 'Forbidden',
[0]   status: 403,
[0]   code: 403,
[0]   body: '{"error":"Forbidden","trace":"c4570338-d808-4900-9427-000113cb13e1","code":403}',
[0]   headers: {
[0]     'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;',
[0]     'content-length': '80',
[0]     'content-type': 'application/json',
[0]     'x-dp-watson-tran-id': 'c4570338-d808-4900-9427-000113cb13e1',
[0]     'x-request-id': 'c4570338-d808-4900-9427-000113cb13e1',
[0]     'x-global-transaction-id': 'c4570338-d808-4900-9427-000113cb13e1',
[0]     server: 'watson-gateway',
[0]     'x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt': '140',
[0]     'x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency': '7',
[0]     date: 'Fri, 15 Jan 2021 15:56:51 GMT',
[0]     connection: 'close'
[0]   }
[0] }
```

Comment: What does `console.log(err);` show? You might need to put it before `res.send(..` to log something.

Comment: console.log(err) shows "There was an error processing your request." I edited my question above and put the screen from http://localhost:9000/api/watson/session

Comment: That is the response as shown in the browser, ie the output from `res.send(`. I meant the server side log, where `console.log` writes to.

Comment: I put the above what my terminal says. not sure what you mean :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

```
Forbidden: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

indicates that either you are using the wrong key, or that the key does not match the endpoint that you are using.

The Watson service documentation describes how to generate IAM keys - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson?topic=watson-iam

Once it is generated, then check your endpoint as you will need to add it to your code. See https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=python#service-endpoint

eg.

```js
assistant.set_service_url('https://api.us-east.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com')
```